# Determinant rule

Tags: determinant

I have problems understanding which determinant rules where used to get this equation here. 
$E$ is $n$ x $n$ and $H$ is $m$ x $m$ matrix, I hope you understand other dimensions from that

$$\begin{align}
\det D(G)=&\det
\begin{pmatrix}
0&\overline a & \overline f \\
\overline b & E-\left(b_i+a_j\right) & 0 \\
\overline g & 0 & H-\left(g_i+f_j\right)
\end{pmatrix}
\\=&\det
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & \overline a \\
\overline b & E - \left(b_i + a_j\right)
\end{pmatrix}
\det\left(H-\left(g_i+f_j\right)\right)\\
&+\det
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & \overline a \\
\overline g & H-\left(g_i+f_j\right)
\end{pmatrix}
\det\left(E-\left(b_i+a_j\right)\right)
\end{align}$$

Whole text is here http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~ronspubs/77_01_distance_matrix.pdf  .

Comment: I learned this method and wrote a computer program for it back in 1977 so I could use Cramer's rule to solve simultaneous equations. Since then, I've found the rule of Sarrus to be much simpler for my needs.

Answer (score -1):

They've divided up a matrix of the form $$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & A & B\\ C& D&0\\ E&0&F \end{bmatrix}$$ and they are telling you that its determinant is equal to a combination of determinants of smaller matrices.  Specifically,
$$\det \begin{bmatrix} 0 & A \\ C& D \end{bmatrix} \times \det \begin{bmatrix} F \end{bmatrix} + \det \begin{bmatrix} 0 & B\\ E&F \end{bmatrix} \times \det  \begin{bmatrix} D \end{bmatrix} .$$

Comment: Where can I find proof of that?

Comment: This result is not true